# Remote Desktop Server does not update group policies

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop-services

I have a domain with 4 Remote Desktop Servers running Win2k8 R2.

If i change the GPO on my domain controller for the Remote Desktop Servers i am having some issues.

After running:

```
gpupdate /force
```

I get a successful response on all the servers.

On 2 of my Remote Desktop Servers the GPO updates are applied correctly.
On 2 other Remote Desktop Servers the GPO updates are not applied correctly. The old settings still apply here.

gpresult /H result.html
shows that last update date is from when i ran gpupdate /force
and gives the new configures GPO on the last 2 terminals and the old GPO on the first 2 terminals.

I am unable to determine how and why those terminals fail to update to the correct GPO. How can i debug this?

Comment: Try clearing the Group Policy cache locations - delete the folders ProgramData\GroupPolicy and ProgramData\Microsoft\GroupPolicy. Then rerun gpupdate. If things still aren't working after that, have a look at your event log and update your question with anything relevant.

Comment: These folders only contains 1 other empty folder Trace, and nothing special in event viewer just: "The Group Policy settings for the user were processed successfully. New settings from 2 Group Policy objects were detected and applied."

Comment: Are all four of your RDS servers in the same organizational unit? Do the GPOs have any security filtering or WMI filters set on them?

Answer (score 0):

I asume you have more then 1 DC . These 2 servers are using a DC that is not synchronized yet, you can do this in "Active directory sites and services".

Comment: It is correct that we have more than 1 DC. I did try to force replication via AD Sites & Services. But if i open gpedit.msc on any DC, it shows the updated settings.